# How to remove the first two characters of the file name when it is a hypen?

Tags: bash, regex

I have a bunch of mp3 files named `- foo - bar.mp3`. My goal is to remove the first hyphen and the first space on the terminal (Bash), which would give `foo - bar.mp3`. I tried it with `rename 's/^..//' *` which works fine for files named `foo.mp3`. However, I get "Unknown option: - foo_1 - bar.mp3" for each file. Who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--` to indicate the end of options, so that filenames starting with `-` are treated as filename arguments:

```
rename -n 's/^..//' -- *.mp3
```

Ex.

```
$ rename -n 's/^..//' *.mp3
Unknown option:  foo - bar.mp3
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr
    [ files ]
```

whereas

```
$ rename -n 's/^..//' -- *.mp3
rename(- foo - bar.mp3, foo - bar.mp3)
```